# The fastest way to read input in Python

Tags: python, input, python-3.x, readfile

I want to read a huge text file that contains list of lists of integers.
Now I'm doing the following:

```
G = []
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        G.append(list(map(int,line.split())))
```

However, it takes about 17 secs (via timeit). Is there any way to reduce this time? Maybe, there is a way not to use map.

Comment: Try list-comprehension.

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `numpy` here?

Comment: Define "huge".  Also, does each line have the same number of integers?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser actually in this example there is the same number of integers, two elements. Huge > 5M lines.

Answer (score 25):

numpy has the functions `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt`, but neither is particularly fast.  One of the fastest text readers available in a widely distributed library is the `read_csv` function in `pandas` (http://pandas.pydata.org/).  On my computer, reading 5 million lines containing two integers per line takes about 46 seconds with `numpy.loadtxt`, 26 seconds with `numpy.genfromtxt`, and a little over 1 second with `pandas.read_csv`.

Here's the session showing the result.  (This is on Linux, Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. You can't see it here, but after each reading of the file, the disk cache was cleared by running `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` in a separate shell.)

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: %timeit -n1 -r1 loadtxt('junk.dat')
1 loops, best of 1: 46.4 s per loop

In [3]: %timeit -n1 -r1 genfromtxt('junk.dat')
1 loops, best of 1: 26 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit -n1 -r1 pd.read_csv('junk.dat', sep=' ', header=None)
1 loops, best of 1: 1.12 s per loop
```

Comment: +1, didn't saw your answer while I was preparing mine. I just benchmarked the version of the OP too, which takes about 16s on my machine. I also noted, that `loadtxt` is slow. I'm not sure why, I would expect it to be faster (and it should be faster than `genfromtxt`. DO you also use numpy 1.7?

Comment: @bmu: Yes, I used numpy 1.7.

Comment: I opened an numpy issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3019. I can not imagine, that it is normal that `loadtxt` is so slow.

Comment: @BranAlgue: Christoph Gohlke provides a tremendous service to the Python community by preparing and hosting binary builds of NumPy (and many other packages) for Windows. Take a look: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: Hey, @WarrenWeckesser it helped. It read file but took about a minute to do this, and numbers are float type, which is not right. Unfortunately, there is no pandas for Python 3.3. Maybe to reinstall on 3.2?

Comment: Seems not so obvious how to run pandas even in Python 3.2. After installation numpy and pandas for 3.2 got errors:`File "C:\Program Files\Python32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 25, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:38141)
ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser`

Comment: A new question about installing pandas, asked either here or on the pydata mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pydata), is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is based on `numpy` has a `C` based [file parser](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=543) which is very fast:

```
# generate some integer data (5 M rows, two cols) and write it to file
In [24]: data = np.random.randint(1000, size=(5 * 10**6, 2))

In [25]: np.savetxt('testfile.txt', data, delimiter=' ', fmt='%d')

# your way
In [26]: def your_way(filename):
   ...:     G = []
   ...:     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   ...:         for line in f:
   ...:             G.append(list(map(int, line.split(','))))
   ...:     return G        
   ...: 

In [26]: %timeit your_way('testfile.txt', ' ')
1 loops, best of 3: 16.2 s per loop

In [27]: %timeit pd.read_csv('testfile.txt', delimiter=' ', dtype=int)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.57 s per loop
```

So `pandas.read_csv` takes about one and a half second to read your data and is about 10 times faster than your method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest speedup would be to go for PyPy http://pypy.org/

The next issue to NOT read the file at all (if possible). Instead process it like a stream.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are often faster.

```py
G = [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in f]
```

Beyond that, try PyPy and Cython and numpy

Comment: `G = [map(int, line.split()) for line in f]` is faster.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski This line produces map objects:`[<map object at 0x0000000002D28898>, <map object at 0x0000000002D28908>, <map object at 0x0000000002D289B0>...`. But @forivall line works.

Comment: @BranAlgue.  Aha!  You are using Python 3.  So change that to `G = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in f]`.  It is still faster than the nested list comprehension.

Comment: It's strange @StevenRumbalski because your line works slowly:`stmt = '''
with open("SCC.txt", 'r') as f:
    G = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in f]
'''
test1 = timeit.timeit(stmt, number = 1)

stmt = '''
with open("SCC.txt", 'r') as f:
    G = [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in f]
'''
test2 = timeit.timeit(stmt, number = 1)`. `>>> test1
16.291107619840908
>>> test2
11.386214308615607`

Comment: It's possible that Python 3 changed improved the performance of listcomps. Old question outlining this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: @forivall:  Both of my comments were preceded by performance testing, so I am surprised that Bran's tests turned out otherwise.

Comment: @BranAlgue.  I see now that there are two items per row.  In Python 3, the solution using `map` reaches parity with the nested list comp at six items per line and out performs it at seven items per line.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Where did you find this?

Comment: @Bran Algue:  From my own tests.  I was curious as to why our tests had differing results so I pinned down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try to bring the data into a database via bulk-insert, then processing your records with set operations. Depending on what you have to do, that may be faster, as bulk-insert software is optimized for this type of task.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb (for just about any language), using `read()` to read in the entire file is going to be quicker than reading one line at a time. If you're not constrained by memory, read the whole file at once and then split the data on newlines, then iterate over the list of lines.