# Fast ascii loader to NumPy arrays

Tags: pandas, performance, numpy, ascii, astropy

It is well known [1] [2] that numpy.loadtxt is not particularly fast in loading simple text files containing numbers.

I have been googling around for alternatives, and of course I stumbled across pandas.read_csv and astropy io.ascii. However, these readers don’t appear to be easy to decouple from their library, and I’d like to avoid adding a 200 MB, 5-seconds-import-time gorilla just for reading some ascii files.

The files I usually read are simple, no missing data, no malformed rows, no NaNs, floating point only, space or comma separated. But I need numpy arrays as output.

Does anyone know if any of the parsers above can be used standalone or about any other quick parser I could use?

Thank you in advance.

[1] [Numpy loading csv TOO slow compared to Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259393/numpy-loading-csv-too-slow-compared-to-matlab)

[2] http://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/

[Edit 1]

For the sake of clarity and to reduce background noise: as I stated at the beginning, my ascii files contain simple floats, no scientific notation, no fortran specific data, no funny stuff, no nothing but *simple floats*.

Sample:

{

```
arr = np.random.rand(1000,100)
np.savetxt('float.csv',arr)
```

}

Comment: Similar current question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232559/numpy-loadtxt-is-way-slower-than-open-readlines.  Not a duplicate since it doesn't have an answer either.

Comment: Typically what's the shape of the loaded array?

Comment: Please provide some sample lines.

Comment: If import times are an issue, I'm wondering if you save some by just pulling in the relevant parts of `pandas.io` to avoid grabbing the full API.

Comment: @hjpauli, it varies wildly, I have a few files containing data that is around 30x3, many others up to 10,000x9.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: why? The question is clear as it stands, it doesn’t need code or samples.

Comment: The reason I asked for a sample is that it is easy to spend 40 minutes answering a question and then find that the actual data/inputs or image are nothing like the description, e.g. they are in Fortran-style scientific notation. Another reason is that it is required by StackOverflow rules that a **"Minimal, Complete and Verifiable"** piece of code is provided which necessarily includes data if it is verifiable and can be run... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If your Input text-file is simple, why not try a simple c++ solution and wrap it with cython? But if you can avoid ascii-files at all, avoid it. Even the best solutions for reading/writing ascii files are very slow compared to binary files...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just use `pandas` and `astropy` for this. Yes, they are big and slow on import, but very widely available and on my machine import in under a second, so they aren't so bad. I haven't tried, but I would assume that extracting the CSV reader from pandas or astropy and getting it to build and run standalone isn't so easy, probably not a good way to go.

Is writing your own CSV to Numpy array reader an option? If the CSV is simple, it should be possible to do with ~ 100 lines of e.g. C / Cython, and if you know your CSV format you can get performance and package size that can't be beaten by a generic solution.

Another option you could look at is https://odo.readthedocs.io/ . I don't have experience with it, from a quick look I didn't see direct CSV -> Numpy. But it does make fast CSV -> database simple, and I'm sure there are fast database -> Numpy array options. So it might be possible to get fast e.g. CSV -> in-memory SQLite -> Numpy array via odo and possible a second package.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It seems odo uses pandas under the hood, so back to square one...