# Python does not read CSV file properly, could not convert string to float value error

Tags: python, csv

I'm fairly new to coding (and this type of website) and right now I'm having difficulties with python. I need python to read data from a CSV file:

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtext('Users/User/Documents/Data.csv', delimiter=',')
firstrow = data[0:,]
```

Here is just a sample of the CSV (the actual file is very large and contains a row of 2000+ numbers)

```
2   -2  2   5   -4  -2  0   4   -5
```

I want python to read the first row of the file but whenever I run the program it is always saying "could not convert string to float". I don't understand what the problem is here and how I can fix it without making a new file (as mentioned before the file is very very large and it would take me a very long time to remake) but any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the delimiter be tab or `delimiter= None` for any whitespace

Comment: Just to make sure: The first line of the csv file doesn't contain headers, does it?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the quick response! When I set the delimiter to delimiter= None it still says "could not convert string to float" but this time with the list of numbers in the row terminal. And no there is no headers in the csv file. I can link the file if need be?

Comment: Try using [np.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) instead

Comment: @user106039 Please let us know how we can further help resolve your question. Otherwise, if you find one of the answers suitable please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas. It is much [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15097561/1435522) than np.loadtext.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Users/User/Documents/Data.csv', header = None)
```

The default delimiter is a comma, however if you want to pass another delimiter such as tab just do `data = pd.read_csv('Users/User/Documents/Data.csv', sep = '\t')`. If the delimiter should be any whitespace instead do `data = pd.read_csv('Users/User/Documents/Data.csv', delim_whitespace = True)`.

If you only need to read the first row of your data, then you can just do `pd.read_csv('Users/User/Documents/Data.csv', nrows = 1)`

To convert from a pandas dataframe to numpy array, just do:

```
data_np = data.values
```