# Fast data reading from text file in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

How can I speed up the data reading and type converting using numpy? I face in addition the issue of getting numpy.void type objects, because of the heterogeneous arrays as far as I know, instead of ndarrays. I have created a simple test that shows `numpy.genfromtxt` is slower than pure python code, but I am sure there must be a better way. I couldn't manage to make `numpy.loadtxt` work.

How can I improve the performance? And how to get ndarray sub-arrays as result?

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

line = "QUAD4   1       123456  123456781.2345671.2345671.234567        "
text = [line + "\n" for x in range(1000000)]
with open("testQUADs","w") as f:
    f.writelines(text)


setup="""
import numpy as np
"""

st="""
with open("testQUADs", "r") as f:
    fn = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(fn):
    l = [line[0:8], line[8:16], line[16:24], line[24:32], line[32:40], line[40:48], line[48:56], line[56:64], line[64:72], line[72:80]]
    fn[i] = [l[0].strip(), int(l[1]), int(l[2]), int(l[3]), float(l[4]), float(l[5]), float(l[6]), l[7].strip()]
fn = np.array(fn)
"""

stnp="""
array = np.genfromtxt("testQUADs", delimiter=8, dtype="|S8, i4, i4, i4, f8, f8, f8, |S8")
print(array[0])
print(type(array[0]))
"""


print(timeit.timeit(st, setup=setup, number=1))
print(timeit.timeit(stnp, setup=setup, number=1))
```

Output:

```
4.560215269000764
(b'QUAD4   ', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, b'        ')
<class 'numpy.void'>
6.360823633000109
```

Comment: Well after 6 views I got a  negative evaluation, and honestly I do not understand why. I can not believe it. I have read the numpy user manual on this topic, I have had a look to the numpy reference manual on this topic, I have had a look on the web and my question is not solved.

Comment: don't mind i will "fix" it, because this question might be interesting also to others;)

Comment: unfortunately i have a very little numpy experience, so forgive me my ignorance, but would it be possible to read your data using `numpy.fromfile()` - documentation says - "A highly efficient way of reading binary data with a known data-type"...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096269/the-fastest-way-to-read-input-in-python

Answer (score 1):

What you get from

```
array = np.genfromtxt("testQUADs", delimiter=8, dtype="|S8, i4, i4, i4, f8, f8, f8, |S8")
```

is a `structured array`.

```
array.dtype
```

will look like

```
np.dtype("|S8, i4, i4, i4, f8, f8, f8, |S8")
```

`array.shape` is the number of rows; it's a 1d array with 8 fields.

`array[0]` is one element or record of this array; look at its `dtype`.  Don't worry about its `type` (void is just the type of a compound `dtype` record).

`array['f0']` is the first field, all rows, in this case an array of strings.

You may need to read the `dtype` and `structured` array docs in more depth.  Many SO posters have been confused about the 1d structured array that `genfromtxt` produces.

`genfromtxt` reads the file just like your code does, and splits each line into strings.  Then it converts those strings according to the `dtype`, and collects the results in a list.  At the end it assembles that list into `array` - this 1d array of the specified dtype.  Since it is doing more than your code, it's not surprising that it is a bit slower.

`loadtxt` does much the same, with less power in certain areas.

`pandas` has a csv reader that is faster because it uses more compiled code.  But a dataframe isn't any easier to understand than a structured array.

---

Your 2 methods don't produce the same thing:

```
In [105]: line = "QUAD4   1       123456  123456781.2345671.2345671.234567        "

In [106]: txt=[line,line,line]    # a list of lines instead of a file

In [107]: A = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=8, dtype="|S8, i4, i4, i4, f8, f8, f8, |S8")

In [108]: A
Out[108]: 
array([ ('QUAD4   ', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, '        '),
       ('QUAD4   ', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, '        '),
       ('QUAD4   ', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, '        ')], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S8'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8'), ('f7', 'S8')])
```

Note the `dtype`; and 3 elements

Your line parser:

```
In [109]: fn=txt[:]    
In [110]: for i, line in enumerate(fn):
        l = [line[0:8], line[8:16], line[16:24], line[24:32], line[32:40], line[40:48], line[48:56], line[56:64], line[64:72], line[72:80]]
        fn[i] = [l[0].strip(), int(l[1]), int(l[2]), int(l[3]), float(l[4]), float(l[5]), float(l[6]), l[7].strip()]
   .....:     

In [111]: fn
Out[111]: 
[['QUAD4', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, ''],
 ['QUAD4', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, ''],
 ['QUAD4', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, '']]

In [112]: A1=np.array(fn)

In [113]: A1
Out[113]: 
array([['QUAD4', '1', '123456', '12345678', '1.234567', '1.234567',
        '1.234567', ''],
       ['QUAD4', '1', '123456', '12345678', '1.234567', '1.234567',
        '1.234567', ''],
       ['QUAD4', '1', '123456', '12345678', '1.234567', '1.234567',
        '1.234567', '']], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

`fn` is a list of lists, which can have the diverse types of values.  But when you put it into an array, it turns everthing into a strings.

I could turn your `fn` list into a structured array with:

```
In [120]: np.array([tuple(l) for l in fn],dtype=A.dtype)
Out[120]: 
array([('QUAD4', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, ''),
       ('QUAD4', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, ''),
       ('QUAD4', 1, 123456, 12345678, 1.234567, 1.234567, 1.234567, '')], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S8'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8'), ('f7', 'S8')])
```

That's the same as `A` from `genfromtxt` except for the padding of the strings.

---

Here's a variation that might be useful, though it might also stretch your knowledge of structured array:

```
In [132]: dt=np.dtype('a8,(3)i,(3)f,a8')
In [133]: A = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=8, dtype=dt)
```

`A` now has 4 fields, two of which have multiple values

`A['f1']` will return a (n,3) array of ints.

Answer (score 0):

You have also :

```
np.loadtxt
```

You can use it if you're sure that each row gets the same number of values.
But, all is said from the previous answer ;)