# fastest approach to read a big ascii file into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io, text-files

I have a text file with the size of **1505MB** contains float data. The file has about 73000 rows and 1500 columns. I would like to read the content of the file into a `numpy` array and then perform some analysis on the array but my machine has been getting slow using `numpy.readtxt` to read the file. What is the fastest way to read this file into an array using python?

Comment: You say "getting slow". How slow are we talking here? And how much memory are you working with?

Comment: Is it a sparse matrix?

Comment: @user2357112 I have four cpu on my machine and they reached all 4 to 100% performance and basically I could not use my machine to do anything else.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096269/the-fastest-way-to-read-input-in-python (Using pandas.read_csv with space as separators)

Comment: @ChrisP The file contains the probability distributions for around 73000 objects. I don't know how sparse it is?!!

Comment: Do you need to process it all at one time?

Comment: @LauroMoura by using `pandas.read_csv`, I got this error `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory`.

Comment: @Dalek See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557074/memory-error-when-using-pandas-read-csv In short, there's a limit of 2gb for 32bit processes on Windows, but I don't know if this is the case. Anyway, there's also the option to tell pandas the types in the csv, which saves memory.

Comment: 73000 rows by 1500 columns into floats of 8 bytes each nets about 835MB, so you shouldn't run out of memory. It's obviously then the parsing part that causes problems. If everything else fails, you could try the old-fashioned hard way, iterate through each line yourself, splitting the line, casting the results and storing them in a pre-allocated numpy array. (Addendum: as per Saulio's answer, which showed up just around when I entered this comment.)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) reader, which is optimized :

```
In [3]: savetxt('data.txt',rand(10000,100))

In [4]: %time u=loadtxt('data.txt')
Wall time: 7.21 s

In [5]: %time u= read_large_txt('data.txt',' ')
Wall time: 3.45 s

In [6]: %time u=pd.read_csv('data.txt',' ',header=None).values
Wall time: 1.41 s
```

Answer (score 3):

The following function allocates the right amount of memory needed to read a text file.

```
def read_large_txt(path, delimiter=None, dtype=None):
    with open(path) as f:
        nrows = sum(1 for line in f)
        f.seek(0)
        ncols = len(f.next().split(delimiter))
        out = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype=dtype)
        f.seek(0)
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            out[i] = line.split(delimiter)
    return out
```

It allocates the memory by knowing beforehand the number of rows, columns and the data type. You could easily add some extra arguments found in `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt` such as `skiprows`, `usecols` and so forth.

### Important:

As well observed by @Evert, `out[i] = line.split(delimiter)` seems wrong, but NumPy converts the string to `dtype` without requiring additional handling of data types here. [There are some limits though](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays).

Comment: There's no cast to the datatype. `line.split` returns an array of strings, so you'll want to cast that to a 1D numpy array of dtype first.

Comment: @Evert believe me, it works. Probably NumPy is doing the convertion while assigning the values to the array

Comment: That, in a sense, scares the hell out of me: can it break, and when (under what conditions)? Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Comment: @Evert [here is some reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays)

Comment: @SaulloCastro In the case the file has a first line with `#` your function will break down, which my file has.

Comment: @Dalek: it shouldn't be too hard to modify that function to ignore those lines, right?

Comment: @downvoter tou shout leave a comment to let us know why you don't agree with this approach