# Fastest/most optimized way to read/write ASCII file in python

Tags: python, numpy, io, ascii

Let me update my question, I have an ascii file(7G) which has around 100M lines.  I read this file using :

```
f=np.loadtxt(os.path.join(dir,myfile),delimiter=None,skiprows=0) 

x=f[:,1] 
y=f[:,2] 
z=f[:,3] 
id=f[:,0]
```

I will need the x,y,z and id arrays later for interpolations. The problem is reading the file takes around 80 min while the interpolation only takes 15 min.

I tried to get the memory increment used by each line of the script using python memory_profiler module.

The following line which reads the entire 7.4 GB file increments the memory usage by 3206.898 MiB (3.36 GB). First question is Why it does not increment the memory usage by 7.4 GB?

```
f=np.loadtxt(os.path.join(dir,myfile),delimiter=None,skiprows=0)
```

The following 4 lines do not increment the memory at all.

```
x=f[:,1] 
y=f[:,2] 
z=f[:,3] 
id=f[:,0]
```

Finally I still would appreciate if you could recommend me what is the most optimized way to read/write to files in python? are `numpy np.loadtxt` and `np.savetxt` the best?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: you're reading text files but it's converted to numerical binary data: binary weighs less than text. You should consider store your files as binary, using scipy or a custom format (maybe pickle would do). You'll save time.

Comment: _"Why it does not increment the memory usage by 7.4 GB"_ - because the string "1.2345667892323" uses up more space in memory than the 8 bytes needed by a `double`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096269/the-fastest-way-to-read-input-in-python

Comment: Thanks. Converting my text file to  binary pickles  reduces the load time next time from 80(min) to 2(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most optimal way to write numeric data to a file, is to not write it to an ASCII file.

---

Run this once to store your data in binary with [`np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) (which essentially is the same as `pickle`ing):

```
np_file = os.path.splitext(myfile)[0] + '.npy'
data = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(dir,myfile),delimiter=None,skiprows=0)
np.save(os.path.join(dir, np_file), data)
```

Then you can load it next time as:

```
data = np.load(os.path.join(dir, np_file))
```

Comment: Thanks. Saving the data  npy binary redunces the load time next time from 80(min) to 2(s). Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

`savetxt` and `loadtxt` just write and read the files line by line.  Save is essentially:

```
with open(...) as f:
   for row in arr:
       f.write(fmt % tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` has a `%` format for each column of the `arr`.

Load is essentially

```
alist = []
for row in f:  # ie f.readline()
    line = row.split(delimiter)
    <convert types>
    alist.append(line)
np.array(alist)
```

It collects all the values of the text file in a list of lists, and converts that to an array once, at the end.

An expression like `x=f[:,0]` doesn't change memory usage, since `x` is a `view` of `f` - (check docs on views vs. copies).

These numpy functions work fine for modest size files, but increasingly people are using this code for large datasets - texts or data mining.