# numpy reading a csv file to an numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am new to python and using numpy to read a csv into an array .So I used two methods:

Approach 1

```
train = np.asarray(np.genfromtxt(open("/Users/mac/train.csv","rb"),delimiter=","))
```

Approach 2

```
with open('/Users/mac/train.csv') as csvfile:
        rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in rows:
            newrow = np.array(row).astype(np.int)
            train.append(newrow)
```

I am not sure what is the difference between these two approaches?  What is recommended to use?

I am not concerned which is faster since my data size is small but instead concerned more about differences in the resulting data type.

Comment: Why not [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? It's simple:  `pd.read_csv('path/to/file')`

Comment: Aside from @Lucas great suggestion, the use case also depends on whether your data contains a mixture of different data types, or is more heterogeneous.

Comment: It has just a single data type integer in the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The fastest way to read input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096269/the-fastest-way-to-read-input-in-python)

Comment: `What is recommended to use?` This is a broad question. What *specifically* are you concerned about? If it's not performance, is it readability, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas also, it is better and simple to use.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
# get all headers in csv
values = list(dataset.columns.values)

# get the labels, assuming last row is labels in csv
y = dataset[values[-1:]]
y = np.array(y, dtype='float32')
X = dataset[values[0:-1]]
X = np.array(X, dtype='float32')
```

Answer (score 1):

So what is the difference in the result?

`genfromtxt` is the numpy csv reader.  It returns an array.  No need for an extra `asarray`.

The second expression is incomplete, looks like would produce a list of arrays, one for each line of the file. It uses the generic python csv reader which doesn't do much other than read a line and split it into strings.

Comment: But when I return it is  a list instead of an array

Comment: That's what I was trying to point out.  The 2 methods return different things.

Comment: So to convert the list to array I used np.asarray