# How to get a 2D numpy array contained in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I stored 2D numpy arrays into a pandas dataframe, which I stored into a csv file. While reading the csv file, I am struggling to get back my 2D numpy array as they are stored as type string... How could I get the numpy array that is inside the string?

For example I have '[1.34 5.43]' and I want to convert to [1.34 5.43]. Any way to convert numpy array interpreted as string into numpy array?

SOLUTION: This was the solution [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy/26296194

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy reading a csv file to an numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252496/numpy-reading-a-csv-file-to-an-numpy-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read CSV data into a record array in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy)

Comment: How large were those arrays?  It is awkward, though not impossiible to recover arrays that were saved a strings to a csv.  It's better to use a different save method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the genfromtxt function.

```
import numpy as np
#create the array 
arr=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
#save as a text file
np.savetxt("arr.csv", arr, delimiter=",")
from numpy import genfromtxt
#generate array from text file
my_data = genfromtxt('arr.csv', delimiter=',')
type(my_data)
```

> Output

```
numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. The numpy arrays are stored as string in the csv file. When I load the csv file, I want that each cell to be interpreted as a numpy array and not as a string

Comment: How does your csv file looks like ? Here the csv file is in string but genfromtxt converts into a numpy array type.

Comment: I don't want to store all the values as a numpy array. I want to load my values in a pandas dataframe with each value being a numpy array

Comment: @user7924113 I think without any reproducible example of input and output it will be a bit hard to understand your problem

Comment: This was the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list